# Entity DataSource Include Feature

Tags: c#, linq, include, linq-to-entities, entitydatasource

I am using `Linq to Entity` and `Entity Datasource`. I have an `edmx` file that contains all of my tables. I am trying to use the include feature on the `entity datasource` properties.

```
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="EntityDataSource2" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="name=sspEntities" DefaultContainerName="xxx" 
        EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Employee_Financial" 
        Include="Bank_Branch,Employee_Personal_Info,COA" EnableDelete="True" >
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
```

This is an example of one of my datasource.

```
 Text='<%# Eval("Employee_Personal_Info.Firstname") + " " + Eval("Employee_Personal_Info.Surname") %>'></asp:Label>
```

This is how i implement it in my `gridview` (a label).

Now i am able to do this because `table A` (Employee_Financial) has a foreign key in `table B`(Employee_Personal_Info). Hence my `include` statement works.

HERE IS MY ISSUE><
Using my example above. Lets say  `table A` has a foreign key in `table B` and `table B` has a foreign key in a `table C`. Using my `gridview` and `entity datasource` how can i use the `include` feature to get a value from table C. Table A only has access to table B (hence i can get value from table B) but I need values from Table C (and i cannot `include` Table C in my `entity datasource` because A and C are not linked).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by chaining the relevant properties together in the `Include` attribute like so: `Employee_Personal_Info.TableC`.